# How to install cloud9 on windows

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, node-modules

I had followed this link "https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9#installation-on-windows-experimental" for installation of cloud9 on windows but i'm geting error on "node server.js [args]". the exactly getting error is cannot find the module.Can anyone please help me on this issue.

thanks,
Pradeep

Comment: Hi Guys,

We want to configure desktop version of Cloud 9 in our local Windows 7 system. We don't want to work on web browser as we are not connected to internet 24x7. What are the possibilities having this? Please help us with some documentation or any support in this regard. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install all the required library packages like

```
libxml2-dev
```

which are given in the requirements section of the given link

https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9?source=c